# JavaFX - I cannot change the text of a TextField unless I do it from this one method and it really only happens in this method, in my controller class

Tags: java, javafx

my program is really simple, it's just two scenes, the second scene just says "this is the second scene" and in the first scene you have to select a folder which will then appear in an un-editable TextField. you can go back and forth between these two scenes using a back and next button. The problem is, when I go to the second scene then go back to the first scene, the TextField is empty, when it should really be displaying the path of the folder I selected before, but when I reselect the folder it shows again, but every time I change the scene, it disappears. The FX:id of the TextField is textfield. I tried making it so that it again sets the text to the path of the folder but this time in the "back" method for the back button. But this never works if it's not in the OpenFolder method for some reason, it doesn't work anywhere else. I want to know why it only works in the OpenFolder method and not anywhere else. This is my controller class:

```
package sample;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.DirectoryChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;

public class Controller {

private Stage stage;
private Scene scene;
private Parent root;

public Controller() {

}
@FXML
public void Next(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("scene2.fxml"));
    stage = ((Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow()); 
    scene = new Scene(root);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
@FXML
public void Back(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("scene1.fxml"));
    stage = ((Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow()); 
    scene = new Scene(root);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

@FXML
private TextField textfield = new TextField();
@FXML
private AnchorPane anchorid1;
@FXML
public static File thefolder;
@FXML
DirectoryChooser SongsOpener;
@FXML
public File OpenFolder(){
    final DirectoryChooser SongsOpener = new DirectoryChooser();
    stage = (Stage) anchorid1.getScene().getWindow();
    thefolder = SongsOpener.showDialog(stage);
    if (thefolder != null){
        textfield.setText(thefolder.getAbsolutePath());
    }
    return thefolder;
}
}
```

This is my FXML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>

<AnchorPane fx:id="anchorid1" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="411.0" prefWidth="1000.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/16" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <children>
      <Text layoutX="326.0" layoutY="76.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="This is scene 1">
         <font>
            <Font size="33.0" />
         </font>
      </Text>
      <Button layoutX="939.0" layoutY="373.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#Next" text="Next" />
      <Label layoutX="63.0" layoutY="117.0" prefHeight="18.0" prefWidth="122.0" text="Songs folder :">
         <font>
            <Font size="20.0" />
         </font></Label>
      <Button layoutX="888.0" layoutY="121.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#OpenFolder">
         <graphic>
            <ImageView fitHeight="18.0" fitWidth="17.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
               <image>
                  <Image url="@../toppng.com-folder-icon-png-transparent-black-and-white-folder-ico-1589x1366.png" />
               </image>
            </ImageView>
         </graphic>
      </Button>
      <TextField fx:id="textfield" layoutX="190.0" layoutY="119.0" prefHeight="23.0" prefWidth="685.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Here it shows the path in the TextField after I selected the folder [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCF8s.png)

But when I go to the next scene and come back, it disappears : [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhSrZ.png)

Comment: Ok, I think i have an idea, you only set the text once you open a folder. however when you change scenes and return to a previous scene. you arent really "returning" its a new scene that you reload from the file. So what you should do, is store the path in a variable, or since you have a folder selected, reload the scene, if folder is not null, set the text

Comment: yeah I did tried doing that in the Back method when it recreates the first scene based on the FXML but for some reason, even then it doesn't show it

Comment: can you show us the attempt?

Comment: `@FXML
    public void Back(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("scene1.fxml"));
        stage = ((Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow()); 
        scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        if (thefolder != null){
            textfield.setText(thefolder.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }
`

Comment: ok, was there any error messages? or it just didnt load at all? could you verify that your thefolder was not null?

Comment: yes thefolder wasn't null and it didn't give any errors, it just showed a blank TextField

Comment: hmm, using a separate controller class might be good practice, but it would change the structure of your code significantly. i m afraid i dont have a good solution

Comment: Either: 1. Don't reload the FXML each time. Load each FXML once, and arrange to switch between the existing views. Reloading the FXML creates a new view (new instances of all your controls, including the text field). Or: 2. Create a model representing the current state (including the text in the text field) and update the text field from the model every time you load the FXML. And, yes, you should not use the same controller for different FXML files.

Comment: how can I make a model of the current state, could give an example of what models are

Comment: I just mean "model" in the usual MVC sense.

Comment: and how can I make it so that it just switches the views each time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every time you load a FXML file, the `FXMLLoader` creates a new set of controls corresponding to the elements in the FXML file. So if you reload the first view, you get a new `TextField`, which obviously does not contain the same text as the previous `TextField` unless you explicitly set the text.

So you can either avoid reloading the FXML files every time (first solution below), or create a mechanism by which you update the text field with the correct value every time you load the FXML (second solution below, using a model and binding to update the text field).

Note also that there's absolutely no reason to create new `Scene`s every time you change the view. Just use a single scene and replace its `root`.

## Solution loading each view once

So one way to fix this is to just load each FXML once, and then arrange to switch between the two views in the controllers:

`App.java`:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;


public class App extends Application {


    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader1 = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("View1.fxml"));
        Parent view1 = loader1.load();
        
        FXMLLoader loader2 = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("View2.fxml"));
        Parent view2 = loader2.load();
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(view1);
        
        View1Controller controller1 = loader1.getController();
        View2Controller controller2 = loader2.getController();
        
        controller1.setOnNext(() -> scene.setRoot(view2));
        controller2.setOnBack(() -> scene.setRoot(view1));
        
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

`View1Controller.java`:

```
import java.io.File;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.DirectoryChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class View1Controller {

    private Runnable onNext = () -> {};
    
    @FXML
    private TextField textfield ;
    
    public void setOnNext(Runnable onNext) {
        this.onNext = onNext ;
    }
    
    @FXML
    private void next() {
        onNext.run();
    }
    
    @FXML
    public void openFolder(){
        final DirectoryChooser songsOpener = new DirectoryChooser();
        Stage stage = (Stage) textfield.getScene().getWindow();
        File thefolder = songsOpener.showDialog(stage);
        if (thefolder != null){
            textfield.setText(thefolder.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }
}
```

`View2Controller.java`

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;

public class View2Controller {
    
    private Runnable onBack = () -> {} ;
    
    public void setOnBack(Runnable onBack) {
        this.onBack = onBack ;
    }
    
    @FXML
    private void back() {
        onBack.run();
    }

}
```

`View1.fxml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="411.0" prefWidth="1000.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/16" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="org.jamesd.examples.switchviews.View1Controller">
   <children>
      <Text layoutX="326.0" layoutY="76.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="This is scene 1">
         <font>
            <Font size="33.0" />
         </font>
      </Text>
      <Button layoutX="939.0" layoutY="373.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#next" text="Next" />
      <Label layoutX="63.0" layoutY="117.0" prefHeight="18.0" prefWidth="122.0" text="Songs folder :">
         <font>
            <Font size="20.0" />
         </font></Label>
      <Button layoutX="888.0" layoutY="121.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#openFolder" text="Open" />
  
      <TextField fx:id="textfield" layoutX="190.0" layoutY="119.0" prefHeight="23.0" prefWidth="685.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

`View2.fxml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>


<HBox alignment="CENTER" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="org.jamesd.examples.switchviews.View2Controller">
   <children>
      <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#back" text="Back" />
   </children>
</HBox>
```

---

## Solution using a model to store the state

Another way is to create a model containing the data you need, and bind, for example, the text in the text field to an appropriate property in the model. Then just pass the same model instance to each controller.

For example:

`ViewState.java`:

```
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class ViewState {

    private final StringProperty selectedFolder = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public final StringProperty selectedFolderProperty() {
        return this.selectedFolder;
    }
    

    public final String getSelectedFolder() {
        return this.selectedFolderProperty().get();
    }
    

    public final void setSelectedFolder(final String selectedFolder) {
        this.selectedFolderProperty().set(selectedFolder);
    }
    
}
```

Then in `App.java`:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;


public class App extends Application {


    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader1 = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("View1.fxml"));
        Parent view1 = loader1.load();
        
        
        ViewState viewState = new ViewState();
        
        View1Controller controller = loader1.getController();
        controller.setViewState(viewState);
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(view1);

        
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

`View1Controller.java`:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.DirectoryChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class View1Controller {

    
    @FXML
    private TextField textfield ;
    

    private ViewState viewState ;
    
    public void setViewState(ViewState viewState) {
        this.viewState = viewState ;
        textfield.textProperty().bindBidirectional(viewState.selectedFolderProperty());
    }
    
    @FXML
    private void next() throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("View2.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        textfield.getScene().setRoot(root);
        
        View2Controller controller = loader.getController();
        controller.setViewState(viewState);
    }
    
    @FXML
    public void openFolder(){
        final DirectoryChooser songsOpener = new DirectoryChooser();
        Stage stage = (Stage) textfield.getScene().getWindow();
        File thefolder = songsOpener.showDialog(stage);
        if (thefolder != null){
            textfield.setText(thefolder.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }
}
```

`View2Controller`:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;

public class View2Controller {
    
    private ViewState viewState ;
    
    @FXML
    private Parent root ;
    
    public void setViewState(ViewState viewState) {
        this.viewState = viewState;
    }
    
    @FXML
    private void back() throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("View1.fxml"));
        Parent newRoot = loader.load();
        
        this.root.getScene().setRoot(newRoot);
        
        View1Controller controller = loader.getController();
        controller.setViewState(viewState);
    }

}
```

The only change to the FXML files is adding a `fx:id` to the root element in the second view:

`View2.fxml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>


<HBox fx:id="root" alignment="CENTER" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="org.jamesd.examples.switchviews.View2Controller">
   <children>
      <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#back" text="Back" />
   </children>
</HBox>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. This makes things so much better now that I can just change the root while keeping the scene the same. Thanks for showing me how to do this as well as how to store the properties in a model. I'm really grateful to you, I've learnt new things